# avoid too many notification from aws iot

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

I am using aws iot javascript sdk for push notifications (In a nodejs lambda function). When I push one notification to the topic the subscriber receives the same notification multiple times.

```js
  const iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: '1234332.iot.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com'});
  var params = {
      topic: `room/public/notification`,
      payload: JSON.stringify(notification),
      qos: 1
      };

    iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Can you help me find what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for that problem is setting up QoS on level 2 - that's  guarantee delivery exacly once.

From mqtt standard:
"4.3.3 QoS 2: Exactly once delivery
This is the highest quality of service, for use when neither loss nor duplication of messages are acceptable. There is an increased overhead associated with this quality of service."